# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7531)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have upgraded Android SDK 23 to 26 Api library,
  Application is using Listview, Fragment, FrameLayout, Relative and Linear Layouts.

Upgraded Home screen 
  -> CoordinatorLayout
     -> AppBarLayout 
     -> CollapsingToolbarLayout 
          -> Toolbar 
          -> SlidingTabLayout

And Rest of things are same for inner screen.

Question is : Application Launched and Opened a Home screen, after sometime/after a while application gives the following(Below) error and crashed. Not able to find root cause. have search a lot and find, it maybe ListView Adapters have problem. Please give a Idea what i do.

```
08-22 16:46:19.057 5234-6825/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 12989 [2018-08-22 16:46:19.057]
08-22 16:46:19.324 3237-3237/? E/Sensors: inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(32)

08-22 16:46:20.987 6696-6696/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
08-22 16:46:23.282 21569-21569/com.XXXX E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.XXXX, PID: 21569
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7531)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
  08-22 16:46:23.285 21569-21569/com.nimbuzz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7533)
```

Comment: It seems you are calling same method in recursion.

Comment: Hi Keyur Thumar, could you please give a example so that i am able to find right answer.

Comment: Can you share code here?, Will give look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `inflate(R.layout.layout2,container)` to `inflate(R.layout.layout2,null)` or `inflate(R.layout.layout2,container,false)`. Hope it can help you.